# SharePoint List: pass URL param to the SQL where clause

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have added a SQL database as external content type and created a SharePoint list based on that. I saw that while configuring it, there is an option to set a filter. I want to filter  records based on the URL parameter which the list receives.  I tried setting up a column_name = parameter filter, but how do I pass the query string parameter from the URL to this filter parameter?

For example, if I have 100 records for Basketball players, and the URL is list.aspx?team=pacers I want the list to load only the 10 pacers records from the SQL database. I don't want to load all the records and then filter the list using UI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should know about **Data Source Filters**

> When you create an external content type filter, which is known as a
>   Data Source Filter, the filter operation occurs within the SQL Server
>   database. This is important when you are working with lots of data
>   because you can offload processing from SharePoint products to the
>   external database and gain performance improvements. After you create
>   the external list, you can use the Data Source Filter by creating a
>   view that specifies different filter values in the Data Source Filter
>   section of the List View settings page.

Read more, [How to: Create external content types for SQL Server in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section10)